# Porque se usa org.hibernate.Transaction tr = sesion.beginTransaction();?

Tags: java, hibernate

He comprobado que la consulta esta:

```
public static List CiudadesDeUnPais(Country pais) {
        String nombreCiudad;
        List<String> nCiudades = new ArrayList();
        Session sesion = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = sesion.beginTransaction();
        Query consulta;
        consulta = sesion.createNativeQuery("SELECT city FROM City where country_id =:pais").setParameter("pais", pais);
        nCiudades = consulta.getResultList();
        return nCiudades;
    }
```

Funciona iguao poniendo el transacction o si no lo pones ya que nunca mas vuelves a llamar al objeto,. Para que sirve? es importante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto tiene que ver con el concepto de Transacción en una base de datos. Una transacción en una base de datos significa una unidad de trabajo en el cual un paso falla toda la transacción fallara también. En otras palabras puedes hacer múltiples movimientos de base de datos en una transacción si alguno de esos movimientos falla la transacción fallara también sin aplicar ninguno de estos cambios, si no, se aplicaran todos los cambios de la transacción.

En realidad no es un requisito para poder hacer movimientos a la base de datos, en tu ejemplo, podrías omitir la parte donde creas la transacción y no pasaría nada, es recomendable usar transacciones en movimientos donde cada paso que realices en tu base de datos sean **imprescindibles** que se ejecuten y que no fallen (por ejemplo pagos a tarjeta de credito...). Te dejo unos ejemplos si quieres investigar mas en el tema https://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-transaction-management-example, https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Fundamentos-de-SQL-Transacciones.aspx